# How do I transcribe an audio file in python with multiple speakers

Tags: python, speech-recognition, transcription

I'd like to find out how to transcribe an mp3 file with 2 speakers in it. Currently I am able to transcribe however it outputs both speakers into 1 paragraph. I see that google has some tools to help with this however I do not want to link this to a google api service as I need to test the accuracy of the speech recognition against a large volume of audio files before billing can occur.
Any help with this as well as improving the dictionary would be highly appreciated :)

The code I have so far is :

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("transcript.mp3")
sound.export("transcript.wav", format="wav")

                                                   
AUDIO_FILE = "transcript.wav"                                     
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:                  
        audio = r.record(source)              
        try:
            print(r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-ZA'))
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Google's docs for speaker diarization](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multiple-voices) along with this library as a code reference, specifically check out the code in `google_speech_wrapper.py` https://github.com/saharmor/fullstack-transcribe

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library